# Suggestion for FB meta tags using jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery

here is my problem:

i have FB app, where i am getting data from json and using that data for making list of items in my main window, i can click on every item, and after i click it opens in new ajax window where i get more info about that item

problem is about meta tags for FB, cos i have LIKE button for every item, so when i click on it, i can post that item on FB wall with infomations like title, picture and description

i have this situation:
when i click on item in my main window, it opens in new ajax window, and i manually add item it to the URL like this:

```
window.location.href=window.location.href + "?id=" + ID + "#id=" + ID;
```

and php code is this:

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){

    $json = file_get_contents("http:....." . $_GET['id'] . "&...");
    $json_array = json_decode($json);
    print '<meta property="og:title"       content="' . $json_array->title . '" /> ';
    }
?>
```

it all work all right, but i get problem with refreshing page, cos every time i click on item in my main window it open new window cos i add GET parameter in url

so how can i avoid refreshing page and still have functionality for describe like option on FB wall

Answer (score 0):

If you have a like button for every item in a list, this means you also have a corresponding page for each item too, right? If so, cant you have he meta tags predefined on each lf those pages?

Facebooks likes are designed to like pages so other friends can click through and see the page that the users liked.

Comment: no, it is all the same page, just ajax function shows other content depends on item click, cannot predefine it cos FB caches meta tags, so i can put just static meta tags so for every like it would be the same

Comment: like i wrote in my first post it works dynamically, but problem is when i add GET parameter in URL it refresh my page, and just wanna avoid it